# OpenGL/GLM Camera

Tags: opengl, camera, glm

I want to make a camera that can freely look and walk on X/Z plane and rotate 360 degrees. I'm using OpenGL and the `lookAt` function from the [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/index.html) library to create the view matrix. I've looked through tutorials but many of them use trigonometry and I can't quite understand why it's used like below:

```
glm::vec3 direction(
    cos(verticalAngle) * sin(horizontalAngle),
    sin(verticalAngle),
    cos(verticalAngle) * cos(horizontalAngle)
);
```

I tried to rotate the horizontal view of the camera by multiplying a rotation matrix of Y axis with the center vector (the vector that represents which point camera is looking at), but the result was that the objects in the scene kept on self-rotating. How can I achieving creating a camera that can walk on the X/Z plane and look around?